# MVC Improvement - The View Module - 1

Tags: php

```
/****************************************************************
VIEW MODULE
view, view_database, view_message
view_arche_1 (external), view_arche_2 (external) - these are 
  primarily html files 
****************************************************************/

/*view*/

class view extends database
  {
  }

/*view_db*/

class view_db extends view
  {
  function __construct($type)
    {
    parent::__construct();    
    $this->invoke($type);
    }
  private function invoke($type)
    {
    switch ($type) 
      {
      case "bookmarks":
        $this->html_bookmarks();
        break;
      case "tweets":
        $this->html_tweets();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Exception('Invalid View Type');
        break;
      }
    }
  private function html_bookmarks()
    {
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM bo  WHERE email='$email' ORDER BY name ASC");
    $html_string='';
    while ($ass_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {
      $fav=$this->favicon($ass_array['url']);
      $html_string = $html_string . "<img name='bo_im' class='c' src='$fav' onerror='i_bm_err(this)'><a target='_blank' name='a1' class='b' href = $ass_array[url]>$ass_array[name]</a>";
      }      
    echo $html_string;
    } 
  private function html_tweets() 
    {
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7");
    $time = time();
    $html_string='';
    while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {
      $html_string = $html_string . "<div class='Bb2b'><img class='a' src='pictures/$a[email].jpg' alt=''/><a class='a' href='javascript:void(0)'>$a[fname] posted <script type='text/javascript'>document.write(v0($time,$a[time]))</script></a><br/><p class='c'>$a[message]</p></div>";
      }
    echo $html_string;
    }
  private function favicon($url)     
    {    
    $pieces = parse_url($url);    
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';    
    if(preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs))       
      {     
      return $pieces['scheme'] . '://www.' . $regs['domain'] . '/favicon.ico';    
      }    
    return false;
    }
  }

class view_message extends view
  {
  function __construct($type)
    {    
    $this->invoke($type);
    }
  private function invoke($type)
    {
    $this->message($type);
    }   
  private function message($type)
    {
    $type_message = array( 
    'empty' => '<si_f>Please complete all fields.', 
    'name'=> '<su_f>Only letters or dashes for the name field.',
    'email' => '<si_f>Please enter a valid email.',  
    'taken' => '<si_f>Sorry that email is taken.', 
    'pass' => '<si_f>Please enter a valid password, 6-40 characters.',
    'validate' => '<si_f>Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password.');    
    echo $type_message[$type];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some random observations:

- What does your base class `database` do? I hope not the stuff it sounds like. Your aim is to separate storage and view logic, not add view logic to your database.
- Having both static and non-static functions in a class should make you suspicious (as this is an indicator this class has one then more objective or is inconsistently written).
- Some functions do `echo`, some `return` and some call other functions. Decide for one way ;).
- `invoke` for parameter to function resolving? Have a look at the much cooler magic function [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

Some suggestions:

- It is probably a good idea to move the single view operations into it's own classes. This becomes more important when you add even more operations.
- Unify the way your class is accessed and the return values.
- Views don't extend a database.

Easy to implement way:

- Let every view operation be it's own class.
- Define a common interface for all view operations (e.g. `ViewOperation` with one required function `run()`).
- Create one main class `View` that is responsible to resolve view operations to subclasses.

Example implementation:

```
interface ViewOperation
{
    public function run();
}

public class ControllAdd implements ViewOperation
{
    private $_types = array('pass' => '<xx_p>', 'fail' => '<xx_f>');

    public function run()
    {
        $params = func_get_arg(1);
        if(isset($params) && !empty($params) && array_key_exists($this->_types, $params))
        {
            return $this->_types[$params];
        }
    }
}

public class View
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        // More security required here of course
        require_once './ViewOperartopns/' . $name . '.php';

        $instance = new $name;
        return $instance->run($arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I recently re-structured my code to fit the MVC pattern using this guidline here: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/ : I'll add in your suggestions as well : Excellent information.  Thank you.

Comment: Why can't I extend a view from my database...if not how than? Here is just my view module..It needs access to the datbase.  Theoretcially this should come through the controller...but how do I do this?

Comment: You sure can, but that'd mix two differenct responsibilites in one class (storage & view). It's the controllers job to pull the data from the database and put it into the view.